# Unable to find any files or directories after the use of chdir

Tags: python

The following code worked the first time I tried it. The second time I executed it, it suddenly gave the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pcdata' and now I am unable to access any file or directory.

```
from os import listdir, chdir
from os.path import getsize

content = listdir("pcdata")
totsize = 0

chdir("pcdata")

for item in content:
    totsize+= getsize(item)

print(totsize)
```

Comment: How are you running this program?  Are you running it from the command line, or from an IDE?

Comment: What directory are you running it from? You can view the current directory with `os.getcwd()`. Print that in your script (before the exception occurs) and then confirm in your file explorer that the `pcdata` folder exists in that directory.

Comment: I am running it in jupyter notebooks.

Comment: The directory I am running it from currently is pcdata itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was running in the directory pcdata and had to go to the parent directory to get the list. Thank you for your answers.